# Freeze on login

Tags: system-installation

So I'm quite new to Linux, I wanted to try it because windows crapware is starting to annoy me. So today I've tried installing both Ubuntu and elementary os and they both freeze on the first unlock after I install the os. Am I just supposed to keep waiting for something to happen or what? Am I doing something wrong? I disabled fast and secure boot in the BIOS. And I have no idea what else I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Nvm I fixed it by resetting my BIOS and disabling csm.

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Would you mind marking this as answered. And welcome to elementary!